# Simplest OAuth2 client java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, oauth-2.0

I wanted to implement the simplest OAuth2 client from a java web app in Google App Engine.

From an object (not servlet) I'd like to make a request to:

```
https://oauth2server.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

With this request, I'd want the browser to show the log-in page of example.com and then redirect to an url of mine (a servlet in my app for example). The redierct url is set in advance.

what's the simplest way to do this? (even if it's not the most proffesional)

I'm trying to do something like this (google's tutorial [**here**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet)):

```
URL url = new URL("https://oauth2server.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID");  
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.connect();
```

But it doesn't seem to work and I don't know much about networking stuff...

Comment: You're not even in the ballpark. It's typical to use a client library for this, due to the relative complexity of OAuth handshaking. You may try looking at [Google OAuth Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/), but I can't confirm that it works on GAE.

Comment: Thanks @Perception, but these APIs are quite complex, and I'd only need it in this point... I'm so sorry for my ignorance, but what I don't understand is why if I just put these url into my browser it goes to the login page, but I can't just make a request from my app...

Comment: But what is exactly your problem? It throws an exception or didn't connect?

Comment: Get in mind that what your code is trying to do is "emulate"  a browser because the server will return you the web page for the user to be authenticated, possible with some redirects.